# YII2 make crud fields required

Tags: yii2, crud

Is it possible to make CRUD fields required ? In case i have `NOT NULL` fields in my database table i will get `Integrity constraint violation` error instead of simple client side `required` validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your `rules()` the fields you want to be required. See the [Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html).

You can also use [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) to generate the models for you and edit what you want.